# Insert Multiple not empty

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I need to insert multple records i have this right now.
Its adds also the empty field because i dont know how to exclude them from inserting:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

/* as_factuurregel */
$product1 = $_POST['product1'];
$product2 = $_POST['product2'];
$product3 = $_POST['product3'];
$product4 = $_POST['product4'];
$product5 = $_POST['product5'];
$product6 = $_POST['product6'];

$aantal1 = $_POST['aantal1'];
$aantal2 = $_POST['aantal2'];
$aantal3 = $_POST['aantal3'];
$aantal4 = $_POST['aantal4'];
$aantal5 = $_POST['aantal5'];
$aantal6 = $_POST['aantal6'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO as_factuurregel (productid, factuurid, aantal)
  VALUES ('$product1', 'test', '$aantal1'),('$product2', 'test', '$aantal2'),('$product4', 'test', '$aantal3'),('$product5', 'test', '$aantal5'),('$product5', 'test', '$aantal5')";
```

Thanks for helping.

Greetings

Comment: share more code how can you make these variables $product1, $aantal1?

Comment: this is much better. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$product1 = $_POST['product1'];
$product2 = $_POST['product2'];
$product3 = $_POST['product3'];
$product4 = $_POST['product4'];
$product5 = $_POST['product5'];
$product6 = $_POST['product6'];

$array_one = array($product1,$product2,$product3,$product4,$product5,$product6);

$aantal1 = $_POST['aantal1'];
$aantal2 = $_POST['aantal2'];
$aantal3 = $_POST['aantal3'];
$aantal4 = $_POST['aantal4'];
$aantal5 = $_POST['aantal5'];
$aantal6 = $_POST['aantal6'];

$array_two = array($aantal1,$aantal2,$aantal3,$aantal4,$aantal5,$aantal6);

$newArray = array();
foreach ($array_one as $key => $value) {
    if($value != '' && $array_two[$key] != '')
    {
        $newArray[] = "('$value','test','$array_two[$key]')";
    }
}

$values = implode(",",$newArray);
$sql = "INSERT INTO as_factuurregel (productid, factuurid, aantal)
        VALUES ".$values;
```

You can optimize this solution if you optimize your input fields and move them in an `array`.

Comment: one more suggestion, if you have some time, instead of multiple variables use array.. just suggestion

Comment: Devpro thanks for helping you have an example for me?